# Passing values from Activity2 to Activity1 without visiting Activity1

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a `loginActivity` and a `MainActivity`

I have used `SharedPreferences` to store some values in some variables in the `loginActivity`. Now I want to use these values(They're `boolean` values) in MainActivity without re=opening MainActivity. How do I do this?

Also, the `SharedPreferences` are in an `onClick` method for a `button` .
Thank you!

Comment: When opening mainactivity via intent, just set your values into intent like intent.putExtra("key",{boolean_value})

Comment: You are going to get higher quality answers if you show a [mcve]

Comment: You don't need to open an activity to read from SharedPreferences. Can you add some code with an [edit]?

Comment: since value is stored is SharedPrefs you can access it any activity. Just before your activity renders just grab that data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `MainActivity` starts first, and `loginActivity` is on top of it in the stack.  When `loginActivity` finishes, you can read the `SharedPreferences` in `MainActivity#onResume`.

If you mean that you want to do things in `MainActivity` while it's in the background or backstack, don't. An activity that is not in the foreground should not be doing any work, and in fact cannot be counted on to exist at all.

Comment: See e.g. here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/1615430

Comment: @RookieGuy That doesn't address the question.

Comment: having read it again, I agree with you.. at least it shows an example how to use the extras from the intent in onResume which is the common way to do inter-activity-communication

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1.If you have set the values in shared preferences you can access them from any activity with relevant permissions.

2.Pass when moving from one to another activity and close the other one if need.

```
        Intent toMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        toMain.putExtra("bool1", "true"); //Optional parameters
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(toMain);
        //To prevent go back to login
        finish();
```

then from onCreate of mainActivity

```
Bundle fromLogin = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("bool1");
    //convert this to boolean
}
```